# Rails ImageMagic and rmagic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am following the tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=comments by ryan but he state that we must install imagemagic. so what i have done to install it his has follow

```
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "rmagick"
```

in the gemfile. But this still fails when i do bundle. What would be the best way to install it. I am using linux ubuntu and fairly new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run on linux -

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
sudo gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install imagemagick on ubuntu then install the `rmagick` gem.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: This is indeed true, RMagick requires some dev library files when you are on a linux pc you can use the sudo ap-get install command when you are on mac you can use homebrew or macports to install the necessary dependencies